# Jquery writing click event in another function

Tags: jquery, html

Below is my Jquery

```
 function editRow(obj) {
    showPopUp();

     var pr_code = $(obj).parent().siblings(':eq(0)').html();
     var ordr_qty = $(obj).parent().siblings(':eq(1)').html();

    $("#ProductCode").find("option").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == pr_code){
            $(this).prop("selected",true);
        }
    });

    $("#OrderQty").val(ordr_qty);

    $('#add').removeAttr('value');
    $('#add').attr('value', 'Update');

 $('#add').click(function(e) {
    // Do stuff on click
    e.preventDefault();
    var currTrId = $(obj).closest('tr').attr("id");
    if(($("#add").attr("value")) === "Update")
     {
         alert(currTrId);
        $("#popupdiv").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupdiv_content").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#backgrounddiv").fadeOut("slow");

        //alert(currTrId);
        var pctxt = $( "#ProductCode option:selected" ).text();
        var pcval = $( "#ProductCode option:selected" ).val();
        var oqval = $( "#OrderQty" ).val();

        $("#"+currTrId).find("td").eq(0).html(pctxt);
        $("#"+currTrId).find("td").eq(1).html(oqval);
        //$currTrId(':eq(1)').html(oqval);

        //alert(pc +"--"+oq);

        selectedEftReqLinesIdArray.push({currTrId: currTrId,ProductCode: pcval,OrderQty:  oqval,parameter: 0});

        console.log(selectedEftReqLinesIdArray);
     }  

    });
}
```

Here I am trying to update a table rows with my field's data, currTrId is the current tr id, when I click on Edit link a pop up will appear with fields with already filled data, then he can update it, when he click on update button the the table will be updated.

For first time row edit it is working fine, but when I click edit and update another row the both rows are updating, not the current row.

When I alerted the current tr id, the second time it is alerting both tr ids like in a loop.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When does your function editRow() get called? If it's called every time you try to edit a row, it's going to create a new Click() handler for the add button.

Comment: So what should I do, should I remove the .click event when the editRow() called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr SLC was correct, every time when I call editRow() it is creating a new click event like a loop, so just I removed the click event just before calling it again.

```
function editRow(obj) {
    showPopUp();

    $('#add').off("click");

    $('#add').on( "click", function(e) { ........ });
});
```

Thanks